# Do you get penalized if you ask too many questions?

Tags: discussion

I've been having to ask a LOT of questions on SO lately - I'm a lone developer at my company working on a lot of different tech stacks and I don't really have anyone reliable in house to ask for help. My specific question is do I lose points if I max out my allotted daily/monthly quota?

I make sure to research my questions thoroughly, and include links to previous answers and resources that didn't help me. I work hard to make sure I provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for every question I ask.